# Dimension of a maximal vector subspace of $M_3(\mathbb{C})$ which is commutative under the multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector subspace of $M_3(\mathbb{C})$ satisfying following properties:
>   (A) for every $A,B \in V$, $AB = BA$;
>   (B) if $W$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector subspace of $M_3(\mathbb{C})$ which contains $V$ as a proper subset, then there exists $A,B \in W$ such that $AB \neq BA$.
>   Then what is $\dim V$?

The vector space V generated by 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0& 0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0& 0\end{bmatrix} \text{ and }
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0& 1\end{bmatrix},$$
satisfies these properties.
So I think $\dim V = 3$ in general.

I think that,  if $\dim \lt 3$, then $V$ is too small to be maximal, and if $\dim \gt 3$, then $V$ is too big to be a commutative algebra.
So it seems to be reasonable for me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It was asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2797348/commutative-subalgebra-of-matrix-algebra, and the approach in the other answer is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We prove that $\dim(V)=3$ by the following analysis.

First we prove that it is enough to consider the spaces $V$ with $I\in V$. If $I\notin V$, then $W=\mathrm{span}(V,I)=\{v+cI\mid v\in V, \ c\in \mathbb{C}\}$ contains $V$ properly and has the property (A).

**Case 1: $\dim(V)=0$**

This case is not possible since we assumed $I\in V$.

**Case 2: $\dim(V)=1$**

We have $V=\mathrm{span}(I)$. 
Consider a matrix $T$ which is not scalar multiple of identity, and
$W=\mathrm{span}(I,T)=\{cI+dT\mid c, d\in\mathbb{C}\}$. This has dimension $2$ it satisfies property (A) and properly contains $V$.

**Case 3: $\dim(V)=2$**

Let $T$ be an element in $V$ which is not scalar multiple of identity. Such element exists by dimension comparison. Then the minimal polynomial of $T$ is at least $2$.

Since $\dim(V)=2$, we have $V=\mathrm{span}(I,T)=\{cI+dT\mid c, d\in\mathbb{C}\}$.

The following theorem will be useful.

**Theorem (A corollary of Cecioni-Frobenius)**

> Let $T\in M_3(\mathbb{C})$ and define $C_T=\{X\in M_3(\mathbb{C})\mid XT=TX\}$. Then $\dim(C_T)\geq 3$.

This is true for $3$ replaced by any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Take any element $S\in C_T-V$ which exists by the  dimension comparison. Then consider $W=\mathrm{span}(V, S)=\{v+cS\mid v\in V, \ c\in \mathbb{C}\}=\mathrm{span}(I,T,S)$. 
This space contains $V$ properly and has the property (A).

This proves that $\dim(V)\geq 3$.

For the upper bound direction, we appeal to Schur's theorem. The statement is as follows:

**Theorem (Schur)**

> Let $k$ be any field. Let $M_n(k)$ be the set of $n\times n$ matrices over $k$. Then the maximal number $N(n)$ of linearly independent commuting matrices is $\lfloor \frac{n^2}4\rfloor +1$. Moreover, the equality is attained.

The proof of this theorem is simplified over time. Schur's theorem is first proved in 1905. Then in 1944, it is simplified by Jacobson: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183505933

Then the proof is further simplified in 1998 by M. Mirzakhani: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2589084.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A48601ff1deca611937144ea64534f3fb

For our problem, $n=3$ and we have $\mathrm{dim}(V)\leq \lfloor \frac{3^2}{4}\rfloor +1 = 3$. Therefore, we must have $\dim(V)=3$.

Comment: \dim works well. \mid instead of | works also well.